# SwiftUI Segmented Picker element is grey and disabled

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, swiftui

I've added a Picker (SegmentedPickerStyle) to my project using SwiftUI as shown:

```
Picker(selection: $selectedType, label: Text("Type")) {
      Text("Translation")
      Text("Highlights")
}
.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
```

But for some reason, the result (both in canvas and the simulator) is a grey, disabled picker (please see screenshot attached).

[image]

What I try to achieve:
[image: Image 2]
Does anyone has an idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try as following

```
@State private var selectedType = 0

...

Picker(selection: $selectedType, label: Text("Type")) {
      Text("Translation").tag(0)
      Text("Highlights").tag(1)
}
.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
```

Answer (score 0):

Your picker has 2 Text items, "Translation" & "Highlights". So your selection will be either of those Strings.
Create a @State variable to track when that selection changes and to show the new 'State'.

```
@State private var selectedType = "Translation"
...
Picker(selection: $selectedType, label: Text("Type")) {
      Text("Translation")
      Text("Highlights")
}
.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had the same issue, but already had `.tag()` on my picker options (as suggested by the accepted answer). My problem was that the binding type was `Optional` (e.g. I had `@State private var selectedType: Int? = nil`). Making the type non-nilable fixed this issue for me.